# Vagrant PuphPet mysql is not installed

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puphpet

I am trying to set up a development environment with the help of vagrant and  puphpet I set some settings through the puphpet website then downloaded the file  when I run vagrant up everything goes fine and I can ssh through the machine but mysql is not installed this is the setting in the config of my config.yaml

```
  mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: ''
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        PMgPjSFyp8dY:
            grant:
               - ALL
            name: dbname
            host: localhost
            user: dbuser
            password: '123'
            sql_file: ''
```

[image]

My question is this : why mysql is not installed does it depend on any other configuration?
or anything is wrong with my config file?

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You should ask this on the official PuPHPet issue tracker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033685/vagrant-puphpet-mysql-is-not-installed

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. It worked for me after I put in a password for the root MySQL user in the config.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment Pupphet has some bugs and didn't meet my requirements, so far the link  provided,
 met with my requirements

https://github.com/bryannielsen/Laravel4-Vagrant

I hope it'd help others as well

Comment: I'm sorry you're having some issues with PuPHPet, but this: "Pupphet is full of bugs and not reliable" is, of course, not true. Each day, hundreds of new boxes are created, the large majority without any issues. Of course, no software will ever be bug-free, and having an app like PuPHPet that has *so* many outside dependencies that I simply cannot control makes this even harder, but at the risk of sounding like a hurt project owner, please keep in mind that I try my hardest to make sure it works for as many people as possible! And again, please submit bug reports to the actual project, not SO.

Comment: I am not trying to find a software bugs, I don't think any bug should only be reported to project owner, it'd helpful here to report them as well some other developers might benefit from it, I just tried to use this website and it failed after searching for a while found that link, I was thinking maybe my answer and that link would be useful for others, Anyway I rephrased my sentence and you can think twice about your vote down